# Escaping Double Quotes in HTML Event Handlers

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

How do I escape double quotes in an event handler in HTML?

For example, how do I properly escape the `bar`, which is a string literal, in the following code?

```
<button onclick="foo("bar")")>Click Me</button>
```

I can't use single quotes for the attribute value since I'm using XHTML. I could use single quotes for string literals, but I'd like to be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button onclick="foo(&quot;bar&quot;);">Click Me</button>
```

And, you can mix them indeed in XHTML, try this in the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>foo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick='bar("foo");'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are some tutorials which said single quotes are not valid, but they are incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure <button onclick="foo(\"bar\")")>Click Me</button> works? No luck for me.

Comment: @Tom Tucker: Thanks for correction, I messed up with other languages. I edited my post.

Comment: BTW, I voted up your answer but someone voted it down, hence zero. :(

Comment: @Tom Tucker: No problem, I was wrong at the beginning. Anyway, using `&quot;` is pretty inconvenient, you could just use single quote or add the listener within separate JavaScript files.

Answer (score 1):

XHTML prefers double quotes around the attributes. But you can still use single quotes inside the value. The follow for example is XHTML 1.0 Strict

```
<button onclick="foo('bar')">Click Me</button>
```

I would suggest looking into [progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/) and moving away from the behavioral attributes.